# In C#, parse a string with no decimal point to a decimal number

Tags: parsing, number-formatting

I wonder what the idiomatic/builtin/fastest way is to do this:  I get numbers as a string of characters, they look like:

0012345
or
001234p

Strings that end with letters represent negative values.  The scale is available separately.

Depending on the scale info, the first could be what we'd normally write as 1234.5, .0012345, 12,345.00, etc.   And the second is -12,340 or -1,234.0 ... or -.001234.  "p" is 0, "q" is 1 & so on.

My first thought is pedestrian what-my-mom would-do string jiggering and Decimal.Parse.

I have to parse tens of thousands of such numbers at startup of an interactive app - so if there's a faster way to do it that's great.  (Though I don't yet know for a fact that performance is ever a problem) I suppose there must in theory be a faster way to do it by writing a different decimal parse that recognizes the numbers as alternatives to digits.  In practice the negative numbers are a tiny minority of the numbers I'll be seeing, but faster is better.

Thanks,

Levin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you know that performance is a problem, code this in the simplest way possible.  Not worth optimizing such code ahead of time, it'll almost certainly perform well however you handle this.